# Свайп Unity 2D. Как реализовать?

Tags: android, c#, unity3d

Как настроить свайп, чтобы получилось что-то подобное:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В моём случае Canvas привязан к камере. И если менять расположение камеры, то ничего не измениться, т.к. элементы привязаны к данному Canvas. Как реализовать такой Свайп, чтобы определенная часть экрана была фиксирована, а нужная область проматывалась и фиксировалась в определенном положении?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в UI у Unity есть компонент [Scroll Rect](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/500/Manual/script-ScrollRect.html), который в первую очередь и создан для прокрутки содержимого. По ссылке выше вы найдёте руководство по его применению с официальными примерами.

Если коротко - то, что вы собираетесь прокручивать должно лежать внутри его чайлда Content. А о настройках и нюансах - смотрите мануал :)

Ещё есть [официальный обучающий видеоролик](https://youtu.be/tcU8yzv_xEw) по нему же